# Getting data from service in controller does not work

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do something simple but I don't understand why it does not work.

I just want to get the `rewards` data in the scope of my controller:

Services:

```
.factory('RewardModel', ['RewardsPromise', 'CardModel',
                         function(RewardsPromise, CardModel) {
  var RewardModel = {};

  RewardModel.rewards = undefined; // init

  RewardModel.getRewards = function() {
    RewardsPromise.getRewards().then(function(data){ // Call to a webservice (GET)
      RewardModel.rewards = data.objects;
    })
  };
  return RewardModel;
  }])


.factory('RewardsPromise', ['$http', '$q',
                             function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        getRewards: function() {
            return $http.get("http://some_url").then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

Controllers:

```
myAppControllers.controller('PromosCtrl', ['$scope', 'RewardModel',
                                            function($scope, RewardModel) {


    $scope.rwds = RewardModel.getRewards();

  }]);
```

In the end, $scope.rwds is empty.
Note that I already tried to inspect `data.objects` and it contains the data.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share some more code (specifically RewardsPromise) ideally via jsfiddle or plnkr

Comment: I added RewardsPromise code (not yet in plunker). thx for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes I'd make to your service (assuming you don't want to combine RewardsModel and RewardsPromise. In here I would make sure to still return the promise (for your controller's use) while still keeping the parsing of `objects` from your data

```
RewardModel.getRewards = function() {
    return RewardsPromise.getRewards()
        .then(function(data){
            return data.objects;
        });
};
return RewardModel;
```

And to your controller, you want to deal w/ the promise here and set the value on your scope once the promise has been resolved.

```
RewardModel.getRewards()
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.rwds = data;
    }, function(data){
        //handle any errors
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.rwds = RewardModel.getRewards();``

`getRewards()` does not return anything. It could return the promise. Then you could the the same in the controller as you do in the service.